# How to write for loop in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the equivalent code of this version of for loop in Kotlin?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    //Body            
}
```

Comment: `for (i in 0..5) { ... }`

Comment: Next time please 1) Look into the documentation 2) Ask a question on SO, not the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i in 0 until 5) {
    // body
}
```

Where `until` is an `IntRange` from 0 to n-1, aka `0..n-1`.

---

Technically if you don't want to use an IntRange, then it's

```
var i = 0
while(i < 5) {
    // Body
    i++
}
```

Though I haven't seen that used particularly often.

Comment: There's also standard function [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html) which can be used instead if starting index is 0.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I forgot even though I've used it before

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
for(i in 0 until 5){
    //body
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this simple case the shortest way would be to use `repeat`:

```
repeat(5) {
    println(it) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

If you need to specify the start, an `IntRange` with `forEach` would be a good idea:

```
(0 until 5).forEach {
    println(it) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

If you want to include the end you would create a usual `IntRange`.

```
(0..5).forEach {
    println(it) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```